# azure shared dashboard rbac without underlying resource access

Tags: azure-rbac, azure-dashboard

i have a few charts and data grids in the azure shared dashboard, for various audiences, e.g. exec, operations,sres. Would like to share the access to read the dashboard to them, but not the underlying resources, e.g. my app services, log analytics workspace etc., would this viable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is viable.

With Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC), you can assign users to roles at three different levels of scope:

- subscription
- resource group
- resource

When you select the specific resource (your dashboard in this case) as the scope, the users who are assigned RBAC role will only have access to this resource, not any other resources. Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboard-share-access#understanding-access-control-for-dashboards).

Please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboard-share-access#assign-access-to-a-dashboard) to assign access to a dashboard. Note that if you don't want others to edit your dashboard, you just need to assign **Reader** RBAC role rather than **Contributor**.

Comment: not working, i grant the user the 'reader' access role, the dashboard show up but it says 'access permission denied' for the particular chart, i dont want to grant them access to individual resources.. this is a killer